# Flutter: How to call images from API

Tags: wordpress, flutter

I have a WordPress blog and I'm trying to create an app for that blog. While using an API for the blog I'm unable to find the right set of code to fetch images that are in between the blog I have fetched the featured image of the blog but the problem is to fetch the images between paragraph text. For now, I'm getting such texts instead of the images. Screenshots attached.

[image]

Secondly, While fetching the text I'm getting the tags along with the text so how can I remove these tags. Screenshot attached.

[image]
[image]

Here is my code which I'm using to fetch all of these:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thewritingparadigm/screens/post_details.dart';
import 'package:thewritingparadigm/service/post_data.dart';

class LatestPost extends StatefulWidget {
  const LatestPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LatestPost> createState() => _LatestPostState();
}

class _LatestPostState extends State<LatestPost> {
  Post postService = Post();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: postService.getAllPost(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text("No Post Available"));
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 250.0,
                          child: Image.network(snapshot.data![i]["_embedded"]
                              !["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"]),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 15.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data![i]['title']['rendered'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 5.0, right: 5.0, bottom: 25.0),
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data![i]['content']['rendered']
                            .toString()
                            .replaceAll("<p>", "")
                            .replaceAll("</p>", ""),
                        maxLines: 4,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              PostDetails(data: snapshot.data?[i]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem can you explain in brief?

Comment: Hey! I've updated my question hope I have conveyed my problem so that you can help me out.

Comment: I think you fetch your API response as an HTML block.
please receive your API response as a JSON object.

Comment: Actually, it's my first time using API so if you could give me some examples it would be great if it would be from my code itself.

Comment: As Huthaifa said, what you're getting is the HTML content of the site. If I were in your situation, I would make an API using Python `Flask` that scrapes the website with `BeautifulSoup4` and returns just the required information.

Comment: use parser to delete html tag. widget only need image

Comment: Can you add your response here too please?

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting from the API is the already pre rendered html content. The code you posted in the first screenshot is HTML code, you can run it inside any `.html` file. What you need is to strip the images from it.

Would suggest first thing is to try to get another wordpress API if possible, to return the images relating to a specific post.

If you cannot do that, attempt the following:

- Parse the entire response as a string.
- Use string interpolation to perform a series of `split()` methods.
- First, split by the pattern which is your base url, i.e `http://thewriting.../uploads/`.
  The above will give you a `List<String>`, each element will start with what is after `/uploads/` and ends with `someImageUrl.jpg somenumber.w`.
- On this list, perform a `forEach()` loop, where you iterate over every element, and then use `.split()` and use the pattern `".jpg"`. It will give you a list of two string, the first element is the url you want, the second element is rubish you don't need.
- Inside the same for each, after you do the split, you take the first `[0]` entry.
- after that, you concatenate your baseUrl, with the image path with `.jpg`. And you get you array of paths.

```
    final String _baseUrl = 'http://thewriting..../uploads/'; //write the entire url until uploads.

    List<String> _list = yourHtmlResponse.split(_baseUrl);

    _list.forEach((element) {
      element =_baseUrl + element.split('.jpg').first + '.jpg';
      print(element);//just to check how the url is looking so far.
    });
```

The above should get you a `List<String>` which has all the images in the response.

Answer (score 0):

use this library

[tap here](https://pub.dev/packages/html)

```
var document = parser.parse(response.body);
        var mainTag = document.getElementById('ppd');


        var imageUrl = mainTag.querySelector('#wp-block-image');
        var getImageData = imageUrl!
            .getElementsByTagName('img')
            .map((e) => e.attributes['src'])
            .first;
        print(getImageData);
```

Comment: There is no library there.

Comment: Sorry, Please check again

Comment: Hey, could you help me more I tried incorporating this but failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your html block to json be like:

It returns a json with an array encapsulating it. For your particular example jsonDecode should work fine, just take index 0 of the array to access the json.

```
var res = await http.Client()
    .get(Uri.parse('https:// your url here'));

var body = res.body;
var decoded = jsonDecode(body);
var json = decoded[0];

var response = 
json["tag1"][0]["tag2"];
print(response);
```

Comment: Hey! I tried but I miserably failed in doing so could you please help me a bit more with this.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the flutter dev cookbook
it could help you allot

Visit https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed by simply updating your environment variables in pubspec.yaml
It should look like this:
environment:
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

The other solution is to remove ! of snapshot.data![i]['title']['rendered'], but it is not the most optimal solution. I recommend you update pubspect.yaml

Comment: It didn't worked any other suggestions?